# How to change the style of the buttons by div which I select?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use  javaScript code to hide all div width `class:article_content` and to display only the div with the id which I selected.But I can understand how to change button's color by article,I look for the exemple in W3School but I use a carusel and the exemple from W3S dosen't work.Here the link:https://carsworldro.000webhostapp.com/button.html

this is the function that fired on each click event

```
function openArticle(evt, articleName) {
   var i, cars_content;
   cars_content = document.getElementsByClassName("article_content");
   for (i = 0; i < cars_content.length; i++) {
       cars_content[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   document.getElementById(articleName).style.display = "block";


}
```

Comment: I don't get exactly what do you want. Could you be more clear by giving more details and providing some code ?

Comment: Please provide some code, and the URL isn't working too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change the button color in your example link you need to add to the function "openArticle"

```
evt.target.style.background = 'red'
```

the evt argument in your code   or event parameter in general  is giving you access to the dom of the HTML element that fired the event

your code need to be like that

```
function openArticle(evt, articleName) {
var i, cars_content;
cars_content = document.getElementsByClassName("article_content");
for (i = 0; i < cars_content.length; i++) {
    cars_content[i].style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById(articleName).style.display = "block";
console.log(evt.target)    ;
evt.target.style.background = 'red'

}
```